# Orthographic change with futur simple of « mener »

Tags: orthographe, conjugaison, futur-simple

Came across the *futur simple* of *mener* today in written form and noticed the change to *accent grave* (è), which naturally departs from the standard conjugation pattern of adding the *futur simple* verb endings to the infinitive.

Is this characteristic of a pattern of similar orthographic changes in the *futur simple* for verbs ending in -ener?

Comment: Welcome to the site! FYI I don't think you can say "salut les gars" in the same way you can use "hey guys" in English. I've seen people use that in English even though women might be in the group. That could make a nice question here, don't hesitate to ask! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's not just -ener verbs, and it's not just *è*.

> Mener / Je m**è**ne / Je m**è**nerai
>
> Lever / Je l**è**ve / Je l**è**verai
>
> Jeter / Je j**ett**e / Je j**ett**erai

When there's an orthographic change between the infinitive and the present, most of the times that change also happens with future simple.